# Symfony - register system - confirm password and hidden input

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I use Doctrine:

```
User:
  columns:
    username:        { type: string(255), unique: true }
    password:        { type: string(255) }
    ip:              { type: string(255) }
```

This generated me new form:

```
username: 
password:
ip:
```

How can i make confirm password and get the IP address in hidden input?

I will:

```
username:
password:
confirm password:
```

and in mysql database will username, password and IP ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];)
How can i it make in Symfony 1.4?

THX!

@@@@@@@

added:

i make:

```
  $user = $this->form->getObject();
  $user->setPassword(sha1($user->getPassword()));
  $user->setIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
  $user = $form->save();
```

setPassword doesn't work, but setIp good work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove fields by setting in the configure() method of your form:

```
unset($form['ip'])
```

And add a confirm password field by:

```
    $this->widgetSchema['password']     = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword();
    $this->widgetSchema['password2']    = new sfWidgetFormInputPassword();
    // Don't print passwords when complaining about inadequate length
    $this->setValidator( 'password', new sfValidatorString(array(
        'required' => true,
        'trim' => true,
        'min_length' => 6,
        'max_length' => 128
        ));
    $this->validatorSchema['password2'] = clone $this->validatorSchema['password'];        

    $this->mergePostValidator(new sfValidatorSchemaCompare(
        'password', sfValidatorSchemaCompare::EQUAL, 'password2',
        array())
    ));
```

You may add the ip in your actions.class.php:

```
if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
  $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('yourformprefix'));
  if ($this->form->isValid()) {
    $user = $this->form->getObject();
    $user->setIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $user->save();
  }
}
```

A small note: I strongly recommend using the existing plugins (doAuth / sfDoctrineGuardPlugin) if you're planning to do this kind of work.

Comment: sfDoctrineGuardPlugin probably doesn't use a database, and I have to use mysql

Comment: how can i add for this password hash SHA1?

Comment: i make:       $user = $this->form->getObject();
      $user->setPassword(sha1($user->getPassword()));
      $user->setIp($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
      $user = $form->save();

setPassword doesn't work, but setIp good work.

Comment: sfDoctrineGuard must use any database you want (hence the doctrine part). If you want sha1 passwords, you should override the setPassword() function in your model like this: function setPassword($password) { $this->_set('password',sha1($password)) }